# UICollectionView Position and segmented Control programmatically error

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.3

I would like to place my collectionView right underneath my Segmented Control, however I dont know if I am getting my constraints wrong. I would like to also place my segmented control to fill the whole frame width minus ten but centered above the collectionView.

Heres the code I have been trying:

```
    let item = ["Past", "Future"]
    let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: item)

    customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    customSC.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                frame.width, 25)

    customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0  // Don't let background bleed
    customSC.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.white
    customSC.tintColor = MaterialColor.red.accent3

    customSC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //customSC.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor)
    //collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView?.addSubview(customSC)
    customSC.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(collectionView?.centerXAnchor).active = true
    //collectionView?.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customSC.bottomAnchor,constant: 2).active = true
```

Here is the image of my output. I would my Segmented View to be my first view to fill the whole width frame and my collection view to show right underneath my Segmented control.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CustomSc on current View not on Collection view .do something like this

```
    self.view.addSubview(customSC)
```

set CollectionView frame like this

```
    collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, customSC.frame.origin.y + 25, self.view.frame.size.width, set Acc. to your req.)
```

Now add Collectionview on Current View like this

```
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```